# What is the rank of a normally distributed matrix that is multiplied by rank-r projection matrices from left and right.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, matrix-rank, random-matrices, projection-matrices

Let $Z \in \mathbb{R}^{m_1\times m_2}$ be a full rank matrix such that $Z_{ij} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Moreover let $U \in \mathbb{R}^{m_1\times R}$ be a matrix with R orthonormal columns such that $U^TU = I$, and let $V \in \mathbb{R}^{m_2\times R}$ be a matrix with R orthonormal columns such that $V^TV = I$, where $m_1,m_2 \geq R$. Then, define two rank-R orthogonal projection matrices $P_u = UU^T$ and $P_v = VV^T$. The article I am reading states that it is easy to show that matrix $X = P_uZP_v$ has rank R almost surely. Unfortunately, I was unable to prove this statement and would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: The statement isn't necessarily true without some assumption on the *multivariate* distribution of the entries of  $\ Z\ $.  Are they independent?

Comment: Yes they are independent identically distributed.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the case where $m_1=m_2$ is even and $R=\frac{m_1}{2}$.  From here I select select $Z:= I$  and orthogonal matrix $Q\in \mathbb R^{m_1\times m_1}$

$Q:=\bigg[\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c} U &V\end{array}\bigg]$

Then
$X = P_uZP_v=\mathbf 0$ and
$R\gt \text{rank}\big(X)= 0$
which contradicts your claim.

Comment: How is $X$ equal to zero ?

Comment: because $U^TV = \mathbf 0$  -- all of $Q$'s columns are orthonormal so any column in $U$ is orthogonal to any column in $V$

Comment: I forgot to specify that $Z_{ij} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, so probability of $Z$ being the identity matrix is $0$. Sorry.

Comment: You are moving the goal post after the ball has been kicked, in fact 2 days after my answer.   This is quite bad.  Also, your new opening sentence "Let $Z \in \mathbb{R}^{m_1\times m_2}$ be a full rank matrix such that $Z_{ij} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$" cannot be right.  If $Z \in \mathbb{R}^{m_1\times m_2}$ then it has real scalars in each cell *not* random variables.  I am done here.

Comment: I just forgot something and added it. I said I am sorry. No need to be angry.